# Why is std::for_each a non-modifying sequence operation?

Tags: c++, stl, standards, foreach

I just read in the C++ standard that `std::for_each` is a non-modifying sequence operation, along with `find`, `search` and so on. Does that mean that the function applied to each element should not modify them? Why is that? What could possibly go wrong?

Here is a sample code, where the sequence is modified. Can you see anything wrong with it?

```
void foo(int & i)
{
    i = 12;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(0);

    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), foo);
    // v now contains 12
}
```

I suspect this to be just an interpretation issue, but I wanted to have your opinion about that.

PS: I know I could use `std::transform` instead of `for_each`, but that's not the point.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See [this defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#475) they say

> The LWG believes that nothing in the standard prohibits function objects that modify the sequence elements. The problem is that for_each is in a secion entitled "nonmutating algorithms", and the title may be confusing. A nonnormative note should clarify that.

But also note [this one](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#969).

They seem to call it "non-modifying" because for_each itself does not exlicitly modify the elements of the sequence.

Comment: Yes, I just found the same issues list. As I supposed, it was just a matter of interpretation (but I really think they should add this clarifying note).

Comment: yeah i think too. it's not yet in n2800. let's see what the next draft contains. as the note has CD1 status, it's strange enough it's not in anymore :) i suspect they removed it because they want to work out a concept for it.

Comment: Nice find! In particular note this in the defect report: "The original STL document by Stepanov and Lee explicitly prohibited the function object from modifying its argument".  I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 23):

Quite simply, you can't make a change that could modify the structure of the container. That's because in the general case, modifying a container can invalidate the iterators being used.

You can modify the element as long as it doesn't change the container's structure (such as the order of elements in the container).

[addition]

---

Note that there seems to be some confusion about `for_each` being a 'non-modifying' algorithm. This confusing situation is summed up here by Stroustrup in errata for the 4rd Printing of "The C++ Programming Language, 3rd Ed." (*CPL*) has this to say about whether `for_each` can modify the elements of a sequence (http://www.research.att.com/~bs/3rd_printing5.html):

> "The `for_each()` algorithm is classified as nonmodifying because it doesn't explicitly modify a sequence. However, if applied to a non-const sequence `for_each()` may change the elements of the sequence. For an example, see the use of `negate()` in 11.9." (recent standards resolution).

The CPL originally indicated that the function or function object passed to `for_each` was not permitted to modify the element passed to it.  However, the CPL was written and originally published before the standard was finalized, and apparently this restriction on `for_each()` was removed before it was finalized.

See also:

- http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/Cuj/03.ForeachTransform/ForEachTransform.html
- the C++ LWG defect report mentioned in [litb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662845/why-is-stdforeach-a-non-modifying-sequence-operation/662922#662922) (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#475)

Answer (score 6):

I think "Non-modifying sequence operations" mean that this operation not modify **sequence**. But operation **could modify container elements**.

Value of container elements and sequence - different things.

Answer (score 2):

As litb indicated above, the for_each is classified as a 'nonmutating algorithm'

STL's 'mutating' counterpart to that is std::transform.

Since you indicated you know you can use std::transform, the above does indeed become the point.  It serves as a point of communication to folks who read your code.

If I see std::for_each, it is clear that whatever foo does, it won't modify the container.

The guideline I follow can be stated:

"If you wish to use the elements of a container to do some task that does not change the elements, use std::for_each.

If you wish to use the elements of a container to modify the elements in some systemic manner or use them in a task that will change them in some manner, use std::transform."