# Using for_each to modify std containers (even though you shouldn't)

Tags: c++, stl

I'm taking a self-study course for C++, learning how the Standard Library works,  and I want to understand how this code that uses `for_each` works, particularly regarding mutating *objects* (as opposed to native data types). I realize that [you shouldn't use `for_each` this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717509/is-it-ok-to-mutate-objects-with-stdfor-each), but this is for the purpose of learning.

I had thought this code would mutate all the elements in the set, but it doesn't.

**My question is:** 1. Why doesn't this code mutate the set?
2. How can the code be altered so that it *will* modify the set? To clarify: is there a way to keep the `for_each` and have it manipulate the set, or is this not possible and some other method (such as `transform`) has to be used?

### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

class A {
    int a;
public:
    A(int a) : a(a) {}
    int getA() const { return a; }
    void setA(int a) { this->a = a; }
    bool operator<(const A & b) const { return a<b.a; }
};

struct myprinter { 
    void operator()(const A & a) { cout << a.getA() << ", "; }  
};

struct doubler {
    void operator()(A a) { a.setA(a.getA()*2); }
};

int main() {
    int mynumbers[] = {8, 9, 7, 6, 4, 1};
    set<A> s1(mynumbers, mynumbers+6);
    for_each(s1.begin(), s1.end(), doubler()); //<-- Line in question
    for_each(s1.begin(), s1.end(), myprinter());
    return 0;
}

//Expected output: 2, 8, 12, 14, 16, 18
//Actual output: 1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9,
```

## What I've tried so far

- At first I thought the problem was that doubler was taking the parameter by value and not by reference, so it wasn't saving the changes to the set. But when I change the signature to be `void operator()(A & a)`, I get the error of:

  ```
  error: no match for call to '(doubler) (const A&)
  ' __f(*__first);
    ~~~^~~~~~~~~~
  error: binding 'const A' to reference of type 'A&' discards qualifiers
  ```

  I deducted that that line being pointed out is from the internal implementation of `for_each`. I cannot make the parameter a const ref, because I am trying to change the `a` value using the `setA()` method, so it cannot be `const`.
- If I change the set to be a vector instead, then when I changed the signature of doubler to take a reference, it successfully doubled the elements in the container. Why would it not work if the container is a set instead?

**Edit:** moooeeeep linked to another question [that shows how to edit each element of a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217878). This is a practical solution to my problem, but my question is more theoretical - *why* can you not edit sets using `for_each`, where you can edit vectors and other stl containers?

Comment: Please, we don't have the STL anymore, we have the C++ Standard Library. It's been a long time since the 90s.

Comment: @DeiDei Even STL who maintains the "Standard Library" [calls it the STL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTeKf5Oek2c). Pointless pedantism is pointless.

Comment: @Borgleader Well, yes, but `stl::set`? That just irritates.

Comment: IIRC trying to do this requires `const_cast` which right there should cause you to want to stop.  A set maintains its sort order by knowing that you cannot modify the element values.  If you need read write access I suggest you use a `vector` and you can `sort` it to order it.

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken, since C++11 the standard requires `std::set<T>::iterator` to be a `const BidirectionalIterator` for the sole purpose of prohibiting the changing of elements in such a manner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ STL set update is tedious: I can't change an element in place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217878/c-stl-set-update-is-tedious-i-cant-change-an-element-in-place)

Comment: @NathanOliver In my notes, it says `std::transform` can only be used on vectors, deques, lists, and arrays (I can't find this requirement on a website definition of the method, unfortuantly). But maybe the reason transform is limited to those types is because they don't preserve ordering, but sets do. Would that be the reason why `for_each` can be used to modify vectors but not sets?

Comment: Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7340434/1025391

Comment: @plasmaTonic Yes.  `std::set` only provides constant access to the elements.  I believe even the non const iterator they added in C++11 only gives you const access.

Comment: "pedantism" -> "pedantry" :)

Comment: @Borgleader: Except he doesn't "maintain the standard library"; he maintain's Microsoft's (Dimkumware's) implementation of it. And, ultimately, he's just a guy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because a `std::set` manages the order of it's elements, it prohibits the user to change it's elements through it's iterators. Which means it's [`begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/begin) and [`end()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/end) methods return a `const_iterator`. You're only allowed to read the element pointed to by that iterator, not modify it (it's const) which is what `doubler()` is trying to do.

[A solution](http://ideone.com/1f3Dln) would be to just use `std::vector` and `std::sort` to order it yourself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class A {
    int a;
public:
    A(int a) : a(a) {}
    int getA() const { return a; }
    void setA(int a) { this->a = a; }
    bool operator<(const A & b) const { return a<b.a; }
};

struct myprinter { 
    void operator()(const A & a) { cout << a.getA() << ", "; }  
};

struct doubler {
    void operator()(A& a) { a.setA(a.getA()*2); } // by reference!
};

int main() {
    int mynumbers[] = {8, 9, 7, 6, 4, 1};
    std::vector<A> s1(mynumbers, mynumbers+6);
    std::sort(s1.begin(), s1.end());
    std::for_each(s1.begin(), s1.end(), doubler());
    std::for_each(s1.begin(), s1.end(), myprinter());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not allowed to modify elements in a `std::set`. If it were possible, then how would it handle something like this:

```
std::set<int> my_set { 1, 2, 3 };
int& foo = *(my_set.begin());
foo = 2;
```

Now there is two elements with value 2. That doesn't make sense in a `set` due to

> std::set is an associative container that contains a sorted set of **unique** objects of type Key.

(emphasis mine)

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

Answer (score 1):

Because the contents of an object in an `std::set` determines its position. That's why `std::set` iterators are always `const`.

Of course, it is often the case that not all members of an object have an effect on its position. A possible workaround is then to declare those members `mutable`. Then you can modify them using `const` references.

To modify a member that does affect the object's position in a set, remove the object from the set, modify it, and add it back in.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply change the key of an element in a key-value store kind of a data structure. (In case of a set, it's only key, no value.)

If you would, the element's position in the underlying container might need to be adjusted, based on the recomputed hash value in case of an unordered hash table, or a different sorting position in a binary search tree / ordered list.

Therefore the API of the `std::set` requires you to erase and reinsert the item in this case.

Which the answers to existing questions in this direction already state:

- [C++ STL set update is tedious: I can't change an element in place](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2217878/1025391)
- [How to update an existing element of std::set?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7340434/1025391)

Comment: Ah, yes. I forgot that sets have every element as a key. This explains why they are not able to be edited easily. This was the point I was forgetting. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, I've learned the following so far:

**1. Why doesn't this code mutate the set?**

Because the parameter passed into the doubler method is passed by value (the C++ default), instead of by reference. Therefore, the *value* of each `a` parameter is modified, but this is not saved to the element in the container.

**2. How can the code be altered so that it will modify the set?**

Not easy to do. Sets (as opposed to other containers such as vectors, deques, lists, and arrays) maintains order to its elements. (Suppose instead that the function used in the `for_each` method negated every element. Then the set would be ordered backwards, and the order the set tried to maintained would be lost). Thus, if you want to modify the elements of a set [you have to do so one at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217878/) (Thank you @NathanOliver and  @moooeeeep for your comments)

**Note**: If the container was *not* a set (instead, a vector or deque), then the doubler method could be modified to the following to mutate the elements:

```
void operator()(A & a) { a.setA(a.getA()*2); }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a piece of cake with a lambda expression.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int mynumbers[] = {8, 9, 7, 6, 4, 1};
    vector<int> s1(mynumbers, mynumbers+6);
    sort(s1.begin(), s1.end());
    for_each(s1.begin(), s1.end(), [](int &x) { x*=2; });
    for_each(s1.begin(), s1.end(), [](int x) { cout << x << ", "; });
    return 0;
}

OUTPUT:
2, 8, 12, 14, 16, 18,
```

Comment: The question is about the set container.

Answer (score 0):

The doc for `std::set` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) defines the `std::set::iterator` returned by non-const version of `begin` and `end` as :

> a bidirectional iterator to `const value_type`

So, even non-const `std::set::iterator` returns a `const` object.

Answer (score 0):

There is in fact nothing wrong with modifying elements in the functor of a [`for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each):

> If InputIt is a mutable iterator, `f` may modify the elements of the range through the dereferenced iterator

So next we should look at the definition of [`set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), note that since [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) clarified this, both it's `iterator` and `const_iterator` types are: "Constant Bidirectional Iterators".

So it is undefined behavior to modify a `set` with a `for_each`.