# C++ functional operator struct not doing anything?

Tags: c++, struct, functional-programming, operator-keyword

I have the following code in one of my problems for a certification program I'm in and can't figure out why the vector of A objects aren't being changed when the for-each statement is called with the doubler() struct. The code is below, if anyone could shed some light on why this is the case that would be great; I'm sure it's something minuscule I'm overlooking.

```
class A {
    int a;
public:
    A(int a) :a(a) {}
    int getA() const { return a; } void setA(int a) { this->a = a; }
    bool operator < (const A & b) const { return a<b.a; }
};
struct myprinter { void operator() (const A & a) { cout << a.getA() << ", "; } };
struct doubler
{
    void operator() (A a) { a.setA(a.getA() * 2); }
};

int main() {
    int mynumbers[] = { 3, 9, 0, 2, 1, 4, 5 };
    vector<A> v1(mynumbers, mynumbers + 7);
    set<A> s1(mynumbers, mynumbers + 7);
    for_each(v1.begin(), v1.end(), doubler()); for_each(v1.begin(), v1.end(), myprinter())
    for_each(s1.begin(), s1.end(), doubler()); for_each(s1.begin(), s1.end(), myprinter());
    return 0;
}
```

My output from the program is as follows: 
3, 9, 0, 2, 1, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9,

I was expecting each of the values to be doubled, but for some reason the for-each statement with doubler() did not do anything.

Comment: Pass by value instead of pass by reference...

Comment: Look at your `operator ()`.  How is `a` passed?

Comment: Also note that you cannot directly modify the element of a `std::set`.

Comment: This is exactly [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851517/using-for-each-to-modify-std-containers-even-though-you-shouldnt/41852333#41852333). I wonder why.

Comment: @GillBates really striking similarity. I smell some kind of plagiarism

Comment: @Ndesai94 where did you get this code from?

Comment: They're probably both following the same certification program, so they're getting the same question (with the same problem code).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker ah that makes sense. I misunderstood certification program as this code being part of some bigger code that can be used to certify something ;)

Comment: @tobi303 : that said - it's still a bit dodgy to have the internet help you get certified. It makes these certifications largely meaningless.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker we should all get the certificate because we helped to spot the error

Comment: I had tried changing it to pass by reference and then ran into the problem of trying to change the set values which I am clear on now. Thanks for the help guys; sorry for the duplicate post!

Comment: P.S. The cert is a complete waste of time.. but the boss wants me to get it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your operator passes `a` by value, making a copy of it. Take a reference instead.

```
void operator() (A & a) { a.setA(a.getA() * 2); }
//        Add this ^
```

Edit: It's been indicated in the comments that you are applying your operation on an `std::set`. The elements of a set cannot be modified. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9600701/7359094) for more information on why you cannot modify the elements in a set.

Answer (score 0):

In your `doubler::operator ()` implementation, you're passing in the `A` object *by value*. It's doubling a *copy* of the A object, not the A object itself. You probably want:

```
struct doubler
{
    void operator() (A& a) { a.setA(a.getA() * 2); }
};
```