# boost::trim each string in std::vector<std::string>

Tags: c++, stl, boost, foreach

I'm currently stuck finding the correct syntax for trimming each string in a std::vector.

I tried

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), &boost::trim);
```

which gave me the following error messages in MSVC7.1.

> error C2784: '_Fn1 std::for_each(_InIt,_InIt,_Fn1)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T1' from 'std::vector<_Ty>::iterator' with [_Ty=std::string] : see declaration of 'std::for_each'
>
> error C2896: '_Fn1 std::for_each(_InIt,_InIt,_Fn1)' : cannot use function template 'void boost::algorithm::trim(SequenceT &,const std::locale &)' as a function argument : see declaration of 'boost::algorithm::trim'

If I explicitly give the template parameter trims second parameter can not be found by the compiler, though its set by default.

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), &boost::trim<std::string>);
```

> error C2198: 'void (__cdecl *)(std::string &,const std::locale &)' : too few arguments for call through pointer-to-function

I was wondering how the correct syntax to call trim for each element in `v` would look like.

Comment: Note also that `for_each` is not used to modify original sequences. Use `transform` instead.

Comment: Wrong, for_each is perfect for what he's doing. Keep in mind that boost::trim returns void, which means that it can't be used with transform.

Comment: Isn't there a boost::trim_copy just for this situation?

Comment: Yes, except that there was no situation in the first place: the OP's use of for_each was fine. See this related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662845/why-is-stdfor-each-a-non-modifying-sequence-operation

Comment: @Diego: Other way around. `transform` is intended to be immutable, which is why it takes a destination iterator.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to bind as well the second parameter of trim (the locale):

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), 
              boost::bind(&boost::trim<std::string>,
                          _1, std::locale() ));
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought about bind too, but I didn't think I could easily add the second parameter there. You helped a lot.