# Which compiler supported with function pointer with default arguments?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, standards, function-pointers

Which c++ compiler can compile next code?

```
void (*G2API_CopyGhoul2Instance)(CGhoul2Info_v &ghoul2From, 
                                 CGhoul2Info_v &ghoul2To, 
                                 int modelIndex = -1); //<--- That's it!
```

It is not my code and I have a lot of such things. I know that standart didn't allow such declaration, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2225426/2210651) comment tells me that some compilers allow it.

P.S. This code from [Star Wars Jedi Knight: Jedi Academy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jediacademy/) source.

Comment: Looks like something we'd do with `std::function/std::bind` today. Alternatively, it's easily wrapped in a custom functor, and `operator()` can have default parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Can't suggest the compiler though I've found a useful link which lists out the fixes that are required to the code to successfully compile it with GCC compiler.

http://www.lucasforums.com/showthread.php?t=203922

Hope it is useful to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but there is no answer for my trouble at this link.
As I understood they tried to compile some sort of development kit for JKA. In my case it's not SDK it is whole JKA (almost whole).