# Transform - a mutating sequence algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, transform

I know `transform` algorithm in C++ is a `mutating sequence algorithm`. But I have never seen anyone using `transform` for the purpose of mutating a sequence. Whenever I search for a sample code on internet, what I get is the transform algorithm used similar to `for_each` algorithm.

Please provide a link or an example , where I can understand the `mutating sequence` nature.

Edit: I got more confused when I went through  [This SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662845/why-is-stdfor-each-a-non-modifying-sequence-operation)
it says `for_each` is a `non-modifying sequence` algorithm. So **I can** modify the elements with `for_each` not the structure of the container.Is the provided answer incorrect. If `for_each` can also modify the element, we can replace `for_each` with `transform`,and there is no need of `for_each` algorithm except that it's implementation may be simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::transform( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), std::begin( a ),
                    []( int x ) { return x * x; } );

    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100
```

The same can be done using algorithm `std::for_each`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::for_each( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ),
                   []( int &x ) { x = x * x; } );

    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Though `std::for_each` is referred as a non-mutable algorithm nevertheless in its description there is written

> 2 Effects: Applies f to the result of dereferencing every iterator in
>   the range [first,last), starting from first and proceeding to last -
>   1. [ Note: **If the type of first satisfies the requirements of a mutable iterator, f may apply nonconstant functions through the
>   dereferenced iterator**.—end note ]

So in fact it can be used as a mutable algorithm.

Both algorithms, `std::for_each` and `std::transform`, belong to the category of **non-modifying sequence operations** becuase they do not change the order of elements of the source sequence..

It seems you mix two notions: mutable algorithms and non-modifying sequence alforithms.:)

Answer (score 4):

mutating sequence algorithm means algorithm will change (modify) the container it works on. In example below, the container `foo` of type `std::vector` is modified.

```
std::string s("hello");
std::vector<int> foo;
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), back_inserter(foo), ::toupper);
std::cout << std::string(foo.begin(), foo.end());
```

The [output](http://ideone.com/M1AJQY) is "HELLO"

This is not possible with `std::for_each`

---

Yes that provided answer sounds correct to me. Also check the list of [Nonmodifying Sequence Algorithms](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/c11-for-programmers/9780133439885/ch16lev2sec22.html) and [Mutating Sequence Algorithms](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/c11-for-programmers/9780133439885/ch16lev2sec21.html) in C++ to verify your assertions.

Comment: Those two links are not accessible.

Comment: In above example, if I create my own toupper function and pass in for_each function, it does the same operation, doesn't it?

Comment: @InQusitive Possibly links are forbidden in your geography.